# Limit access/transmit rights on NIC to a single user application

Tags: ethernet, network-interface, socket, real-time, delay

I currently have a RT patched linux machine and I need to have full and undelayed access to my Wired interface card. I am running a realtime non-preemtable user application which sends a couple of Ethernet frames every 70~ microsecond. However, after testing it can be observed that the Ethernet frames have a jitter of +/- 10 microseconds, while this is still extremely precise I would like to reduce this even further, preferrably to a single micrsecond.

For this to happen I need to disable various applications that would for one reason or another open a socket on eth0 and transmit probes/network discovery messages. Is it possible to do this and if so how? 
Furthermore are there any additional tips you might have as to reduce the time from sending a raw Ethernet frame using sendto() till the frame is actually transmitted from the NIC?

Thank you very much in advance.